# `make gtags` produces empty database on Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

**This is `gtags` version 5.7.1, the one packaged with Ubuntu 14.04.** This is rather an old version of `gtags`.

The Linux kernel has a `gtags` Make target, which [ultimately results in the command](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/tags.sh#L143) `all_target_sources | gtags -i -f -`

- `-i` tells `gtags` to do an incremental update
- `-f` tells `gtags` to read a list of source files (to examine for symbols) from the following file. `-f -` means to read the list from stdin.
- `all_target_sources` is a [function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/tags.sh#L120) that outputs a list of all the relevant .c and .h files.

When I run `make gtags`, the resulting tags table is empty (GTAGS, GPATH etc all have size of 16 bytes which appears to just be a header).

If I modify the [script that generates tags](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/tags.sh#L143) so that it uses the following:

```
all_target_sources > sources.list
gtags -iv -f sources.list
```

I get the same result. The added `-v` gives me this output:

```
checking /home/me/sources/linux/GTAGS
GTAGS found at '/home/me/sources/linux/GTAGS'.
[Tue Jul 05 10:21:49 BST 2016] Gtags started.
 Using default configuration.
 Tag found in '/home/me/sources/linux'.
 Incremental update.
[Tue Jul 05 10:21:49 BST 2016] Updating 'GTAGS'.
[Tue Jul 05 10:21:49 BST 2016] Updating 'GRTAGS'.
[Tue Jul 05 10:21:49 BST 2016] Updating 'GSYMS'.
 Global databases have been modified.
[Tue Jul 05 10:21:49 BST 2016] Done.
```

But when I then run `gtags -iv -f sources.list` directly from my shell (using the sources.list left over from the script), I find that a proper tags table is built.

I've dumped the environment from inside the [script](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/tags.sh#L143), and diffed it with my prompt environment, there's no differences that should obviously affect `gtags`.

Does anyone know of any `gtags` behaviours that could be causing this?

---

[meta] Sorry, there's no `gtags` or `gnu-global` tag and I don't have the rep to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the source of the problem, but after installing the [latest version of GNU Global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/download.html) from source, the problem goes away. So I conclude it was probably a bug in old versions of `gtags`.